# How to Keep a Block in Center when using jQuery Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Lets assume I have 10 blocks for jQuery Masonry, each block(div) width 200px, so at 1024x768, will look like this after Masonry

```
[000] [111] [222] [333] [444]
[555] [666] [777] [888] [999]
```

So, if I change screen resolution to 640x480, it will look like this

```
[000] [111] [222]
[333] [444] [555]
[666] [777] [888]
[999]
```

If I change screen resolution to 1600x190, it will look like

```
[000] [111] [222] [333] [444] [555] [666] [777]
[888] [999]
```

What I to achieve is: to make the first block([000]) always positioned in the center of the screen.
How?

Comment: PRTFM: "Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason fitting stones in a wall". You can not fix one Masonry element in the center of a browser's window with all other elements arranging fluidly around it - you can have a fixed element top right or top left, called a "corner stamp".

Comment: @Systembolaget please put your comments to an answer, then I can "accept" it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRTFM: "Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason fitting stones in a wall". You can not fix one Masonry element in the center of a browser's window with all other elements arranging fluidly around it - you can have a fixed element top right or top left, called a "corner stamp".

Comment: Masonry has a new method, `stamp`, that can be used for central positioning. http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#stamp

Answer (score 0):

you need to use:

```
  $('.container').css('width','1024px');
  $('.container').css('height','768px');
```

or

```
  $('.container').css('width','640px');
  $('.container').css('height','480px');
```

or

```
  $('.container').css('width','1600px');
  $('.container').css('height','190px');
```

to change the area of the boxes then the boxes will appears like what you want.

Comment: No, I like it fill the whole screen, change with the screen resized.